# What is "team" in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I am skeptical about Internet results.

Question: So what is "team" in Latin?

Please cite a a reliable reference page.

Comment: There are various ways in which working or acting together can be described: you will have to define _team_ before this can be answered properly. Can you tell us what situation you have in mind, please?

Comment: I second @TomCotton. I am not convinced that there is a general translation for "team" in Latin, just like in many other languages. Can you edit your question to describe where you would like to use the word? You could also list the internet results you found, and we can then tell you how useful they are.

Comment: I mean the collective,the many,the group.

Comment: bigas was the word I got

Comment: from word hippo

Comment: user6095: Pock. Ox. Lat. Dict. gives "protelum" = "team"; but, on further study this is a team-of-oxen; probably, not what you are seeking?

Comment: What about bigas?Is it wrong?

Comment: Yes, I think _bigas_ will be wrong if only because it means a pair (usually of horses) (assuming it's a declined form of _biga_).  Are you thinking of a team of humans?  What activity are they engaged in as a team?  Your answers may help us find a good word for you :)

Comment: FWIW, there is a scholarly translation of a _modern_ novel that uses [_turma, -ae_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dturma) for a team in the context of collective sports. Is that good for you?

Comment: Yes a team of humans united. Is there one?

Comment: or society.Is there a word for it?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to clarify that you mean a team of people?  Even better if you can also give an example of what they are doing as a team.  Because, in the context of the ancient world, "team" almost always is a translation of a Latin word that means a group of animals harnessed to pull a chariot or a plough.  This is why WordHippo gave you _bigas_ - a "team" or pair of horses/oxen.

Comment: @User6905: While reading "Latin Obscenity" (Wiki) came across alternative for "protelum"--a team of three, as in a sexual threesome. There, a little less boring than "a team of oxen".

Answer (score 7):

Your question was not easy to answer!  The Romans seem to speak very little about working together as a team!  Of course, there are many "groups" of people in the literature but they tend to be groups as defined by an outside observer, whereas I think a team more properly is defined from within and by its common goal.

With that said, however, here are some options that may work for you.

***MANUS***: used typically of a group of soldiers, a sort of team after all, but not exclusively, as the third and fourth examples show:

> *qui eam **manum** habebant qua Uticam diripuerant*
>
> who were in charge of a team [of soldiers] with which they had
>   plundered Utica

Caesar, *The African War*, 95

> *modica **manu** armatorum media ferme nocte Sardis concessit*
>
> he reached Sardis about midnight with a small group of armed men

Livy, *History of Rome*, 37.33.44

> *Erat bene magna **manus** intra Pompeianarum partium*
>
> Now inside the town there was a good large group of supporters of
>   Pompeius

Caesar, *The Spanish War*, 35

> *tamen exposuit **manum** fuisse iuventutis duce Curione*
>
> nonetheless, he explained that a group of young men had been
>   formed under Curio’s leadership

Cicero, *Letters to Atticus*, 44 (II.24), Rome, August (?) 59, Cicero to Atticus

***GREX***: often used to mean a herd of animals but when speaking of people, can mean company, society, troop, or band:

> *In hunc igitur **gregem** vos nunc P. Sullam, iudices, ex his qui cum hoc
>   vivunt atque vixerunt honestissimorum hominum **gregibus** reicietis*
>
> Will you then, gentlemen, now cast Publius Sulla out into that group,
>   excluding him from these groups of honourable men who have associated
>   and still associate with him?

CICERO, *Pro Sulla*, 77

***COHORS***: this is an interesting one because it primarily means an enclosed courtyard, a yard or pen, but that sense of being enclosed transferred to mean people metaphorically corralled off by a common purpose, and thus can mean a company of soldiers, a division of an army, a cohort, or a retinue:

> *inter vos quotiens libertorumque **cohortem***
>
> *pugna Saguntina fervet commissa lagona*
>
> once battle with the Saguntine crockery starts up and rages between
>   your guests and a group of freedmen

Juvenal, *Satires*, 5.28-29

Comment: You could add _protelum_, used for a team of horse (in chariot racing) or oxen.

Comment: @TomCotton  I left out all the ways you can refer to a team of animals because in the comments above, the original poster did specify a team of humans.  I think they have in mind a team of people working together on a project and not teams of animals that pull chariots and ploughs!  Unless of course such terms were also used for groups of humans?

Comment: Too many comments! Somehow I missed that. Splendid answer, anyway.

Comment: Why did grex become gregum and gregibus?

Comment: @user6095 They're different noun cases of _[grex](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/grex#Latin):_ singular accusative and plural ablative.